# Como salvar e recuperar um campo date em SQLite3?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sqlite, data

A questão é que no próprio site do SQLite diz que para campos `date` é para usar tipo numérico ou então *string*, tudo bem com numérico eu gravo no banco a data sem caracteres especiais, porém na *string*, tem algum jeito de fazer um `select` de uma data **"12/10/2015"**  porém convertê-la para um tipo data para usar um `between`?

Comment: Creio q salva como string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar do jeito que você quiser, o SQLite te dá essa liberdade. Alguns preferem formatar a data como `character`, algo como `20160114`, outros preferem usar o [*timestamp*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_temporal) simples sem formatação ou alguma outra forma numérica e guardar como `integer` mesmo.

Se usar um texto tenha certeza que a parte de maior grandeza venha primeiro que a parte de menor grandeza, como em tudo que demande classificação, então ano vem antes de mês, que vem antes de dia.

Lembre-se que o que está no banco de dados são apenas dados. Não se preocupe com a formatação dele. Formatação você faz na aplicação do jeito que achar melhor em cada contexto. Claro que gravará em algum formato, mas escolha um bem simples, como o `yyyymmdd`.

O `between` tem que ser na mão, ou criar uma função auxiliar em C que te ajude nisto e anexar ao SQLite (isto pode ser feito em outra linguagem se ela interoperar bem com C.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).